# What is the equivalent code to the sentence in Python below?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
post_data = None if post_args is None else urllib.urlencode(post_args)
```

I can't understand what this code really do. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Read it as it is.... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
post_data = None if post_args is None else urllib.urlencode(post_args)
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
if post_args is None:
    post_data = None 
else: 
    post_data = urllib.urlencode(post_args)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions), introduced in python 2.5. (It really ought to be on one line).

It does exactly what it reads like -- `post_data` is `None` if `post_args is None`, otherwise it's assigned the result of `urllib.urlencode(post_args)`.

A more verbose way of writing it would be

```
if post_args is None:
    post_data = None
else:
    post_data = urllib.urlencode(post_args)
```

or, using the [and-or trick](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/and_or.html):

```
post_data = (post_args is None and [None] or [urllib.urlencode(post_args)])[0]
```